# A Question Regards Quotient Topology and Vector Space

Tags: general-topology

> Let $V$ be a $n$ dimensional vector space,Consider the topological
>   space $(V, \mathcal{T}_v)$, where $\mathcal{T}_v$ is standard topology
>   on $V$. Standard topology on $V$ is defined by following:
>
> if $\beta$ is any basis of $V$, $\varphi_{\beta} : \mathbb{R}^n \to V:
>  \varphi(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = \sum^n_{i=1} x_iv_i$. There exists a unique
>   topology $\mathcal{T}_{\beta}$ on $V$ such that $\varphi_{\beta}$ is a
>   homeomorphism from $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{T})$ to $(V,
>  \mathcal{T}_β)$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is the standard topology on
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$. This $\mathcal{T}_{\beta}$ is our standard topology
>
> Now, Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ (in the sense of linear algebra) and
>   for $v_1, v_2 ∈ V$, define $v_1 ∼ v_2$ if $v_2 − v_1 ∈ W$.
>
> Note that $V/∼$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space  with
>   addition and scalar multiplication defined by $[v]+[w] = [v+w]$ and
>   $λ[v] = [λv]$.
>
> $V/∼$ also has a standard topology $\mathcal{T}_{V/∼}$. Of course,$
>  V/∼$ also has the quotient topology $\mathcal{T}$ coming from $(V,
>  \mathcal{T}_{V} $) and the equivalence relation $∼$.
>
> (a)  Prove that the identity map $I_{V/∼} : V/∼ → V/∼$ is a
>   continuous function from $(V/∼, \mathcal{T})$ to $(V/∼,
>  \mathcal{T}_{V/∼})$
>
> (b) Prove that the identity map $I_{V/∼} : V/∼ → V/∼$ is a continuous
>   function from $(V/∼, \mathcal{T}_{V/∼})$) to $(V/∼, \mathcal{T})$

========================

here is my thoughts for (a):

Since $I_{V/∼} : V/∼ → V/∼$ by $I([x]) = [x]$ There should be a function $f$ such that $f : V \to V/\sim$ by $f(x) = [x]$. I want this function $f$ to be invariant, which means $x \sim x' \iff f(x) = f(x')$ and this $f$ must be continuous from $(V, \mathcal{T}_v)$ to $(V/\sim, \mathcal{T}_{V/\sim})$

Once I find the $f$, it implies the result of (a). First I show that $f$ is invariant under $\sim$. Also show that $f$ is continuous from $(V, \mathcal{T}_v)$ to $(V/\sim, \mathcal{T}_{V/\sim})$ (This can be done by our construction of quotient topology). Hence, there is unique $g:V/\sim \to V/\sim $ such that $g([x]) = [x]$. And obviously, $g$ is identity map that we want

But, for (b):

$\varphi_V : \mathbb{R}^n \to V$ by $\varphi_V(x) = \sum^n_{i=1} x_iv_i$ where $\{v_1,..v_n\}$ is basis of $V$. Let $\varphi_{V/\sim} : \mathbb{R}^n \to V/\sim$ by 
 $\varphi_{V/\sim}(x) = \sum_{i=k+1}^n  x_i[v_i]$ where $\{[v_{k+1}],....,[v_n]\}$ is basis for $V/\sim$.

I let $g = (\varphi_V(\varphi_{V/\sim}))^{-1}$. Note that $\varphi_{V/\sim}$ and $\varphi_{V}$ homeomorphism and having continuous inverse. so my $g$ is continuous.Finally, I have $\pi(g) = id$ where $\pi: V \to V/\sim$ continuous from $(V, \mathcal{T}_V)$ to $(V/\sim, \mathcal{T})$  where $\mathcal{T}$ is quotient topology

Comment: Don't you just need to show that $\mathcal{T}_{V/∼}= \mathcal{T}$? and for this isn't it enough to observe that $p\circ \phi _{V}=\phi  _{V/∼}$ where $p$ is the projection $x \mapsto [x]$?

Comment: @Chilango ,actually  this question from my assignment. And it ask us to prove $\mathcal{T}_{V/\sim} = \mathcal{T}$ by using the facts from (a) and (b)

Comment: Do you know that **every** linear map $L \colon (V,\mathcal{T}_V) \to (Z,\tau)$, where $(Z,\tau)$ is any topological vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, is continuous?

Comment: @DanielFischer, no, I don't know this, but I have reedited my thoughts on (a) question, could u check if it's correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you write there. Regarding the maps, there's nothing to find, everything is given. For simplicity, let us write $Q$ for the space $V/\!\sim$ endowed with the quotient topology, and $S$ for the space $V/\!\sim$ endowed with the standard topology. We have the canonical projection $\pi \colon V \to V/\!\sim;\, \pi(x) = [x]$. Let's write $\pi_Q\colon V \to Q$ and $\pi_S\colon V\to S$ for the map $\pi$. By definition of the quotient topology, the identity $\iota \colon Q\to S$ is continuous iff $\iota\circ \pi_Q = \pi_S$ is continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer  oh, I get. This is just the theorem that I will use to prove (a)

Comment: @DanielFischer  BTW，what's the name for this theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer,  but still no idea how to do (b)... ;(

Comment: For b), can you find a map (prove the existence) $g\colon S\to V$ such that $\pi \circ g = \operatorname{id}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I kind of figure it out now. But I'm unsure, I would so appreciate if you can check me reasoning (I edit in the original post)